# Format DateTime to specific format

Tags: c#

When this function is called, it creates a text file with these attributes. There is one attribute  known as `start_date`. When I convert to `DateTime`, the date format will be `MM:DD:YYYY` and an error will be shown. I am not sure how to change the format to `DD:MM:YYYY`, I have also read on the `DateTime` formatting but I still do not understand. Thanks.

Code is as follows:

```cs
static void generateInfoForITDepartment()
{
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\notgivingmydirectory\HRMasterlist.txt";
    List<Employee> people = new List<Employee>();
    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string[] entries = line.Split('|');

        Employee newIT = new Employee();

        newIT.Nric = entries[0];
        newIT.FullName = entries[1];
        newIT.Start_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(entries[3]);
        newIT.Department = entries[5];
        newIT.MobileNo = entries[6];

        people.Add(newIT);
    }
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    foreach (var it in people)
    {
        output.Add($"{ it.Nric }, { it.FullName }, { it.Start_Date }, { it.Department }, { it.MobileNo }");
    }
    File.WriteAllLines("ITDepartment.txt", output);
    Console.WriteLine("ITDepartment.txt has been created");
}
```

Edit:
My textfile currently looks like this:

S1234567A|Jan Lee|Ms|05/10/1990|Software Architect|IT  Department|98785432|PartTime|3500

S1234567B|Feb Tan|Mr|10/12/1991|Corporate Recruiter|HR CorporateAdmin|98766432|PartTime|1500

S1234567C|Mark Lim|Mr|15/07/1992|Benefit Specialist|HR Corporate Admin|98265432|PartTime|2900

Comment: Do you mean that in a text file you have a string that represents a DateTime that is formatted as `DD:MM:YYYY`? Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` and provide the format.  `DateTime.TryParseExact()` if the string can be empty (or, well, just use this one). -- If you're the one responsible for the creation of that file, serialize your data instead (JSON, XML): much less prone to errors.

Comment: Do keep in mind that a `DateTime` instance does not have a format. Format is only in a string representation of a `DateTime` instance. You need to provide the expected format when parsing and again when writing back to string.

Comment: Which country uses `:` for a date separator? What do they use for a time separator?  `Convert.ToDateTime` is essentially an alias for `DateTime.Parse` without a `CultureInfo`, which means it uses the current thread's culture. Since I doubt any built-in culture uses `:` as the date separator, you'll have to use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the the format you want.

Comment: I presume wherever this data comes from can't be changed to use the ISO8601 standard format for date exchange?  I still don't get why so many systems developers have no idea what a standard date format actually is! (not complaining about the OP here).  AFAIK there are 0 countries that use colon as a date separator.

Comment: -Pana: The format may also be mm, dd, yyyy (just trying to show what I meant about the format)

Comment: You can pass multiple Formats to those methods, so, include all *possible formats* (is there a standard here?). If you're the *creator*, rewrite the procedure that stores the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is not a valid date format, you need `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`. If you are sure about incoming format is always in `dd/MM/yyyy`, then use `ParseExact`

Here is the example with `ParseExact`

```
newIT.Start_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(entries[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Another example with `TryParseExact`

```
DateTime start_date = DateTime.MinValue;
var isValidDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(entries[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out start_date);
newIT.Start_Date = isValidDate ? start_date : DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: For this part, `22:07:2021`, my textfile has a date assigned to each person. Is this the only way to ensure that the format is what I want to achieve?

Comment: like can i use entries[3] instead?

Comment: @user15930341, yes you are right. just replace 22:07:2021 with entries[3]. I have updated the post

Comment: currently the output is this: `10/5/1990 12:00:00 AM`. How do you remove the 12:00:00 am, as I do not want this output

Comment: @user15930341 DateTime values don't have a human-readable format, and **always** have a time component. Anything you see suggesting a specific format is just a debugging tool being helpful. Instead, you account for this at the time you output the value.

Comment: @user15930341, you can try DateTime.ParseExact(entries[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") again if you want in string format

Comment: Is this supposed to happen: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'`?

Comment: @user15930341, try .Date. example start_date.Date. This will truncate the time

Answer (score 0):

We need to use an option to parse the date from a specific format. While where here, let's improve the structure a bit, and the performance and memory use a LOT (what you had was grossly memory inefficient):

```
static IEnumerable<Employee> readEmployees(string filePath)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath);
    return lines.Select(line => {
        var data = line.Split('|');
        var result = new Employee();
        result.Nric = data[0];
        result.FullName = data[1];
        result.Start_Date = DateTime.ParseExact(data[3], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        result.Department = data[5];
        result.MobileNo = data[6];
        return result;
    });
}

static void generateInfoForITDepartment()
{
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\notgivingmydirectory\HRMasterlist.txt";
    var people = readEmployees(filePath);
    // note the extra format specifier for the date value
    var output = people.Select(emp => $"{ emp.Nric }, { emp.FullName }, { emp.Start_Date:d }, { emp.Department }, { emp.MobileNo }");

    File.WriteAllLines("ITDepartment.txt", output);
    Console.WriteLine("ITDepartment.txt has been created");
}
```

FWIW, I would also tend to update the `Employee` class to move some of this code to a `ToString()` override and a static `Parse()` method, which could let you simplify the code like this:

```
static IEnumerable<Employee> readEmployees(string filePath)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath);
    return lines.Select(line => Employee.Parse(line));
}

static void generateInfoForITDepartment()
{
    string filepath = @"C:\Users\notgivingmydirectory\HRMasterlist.txt";
    var people = readEmployees(filePath);

    File.WriteAllLines("ITDepartment.txt", people); //calls the default ToString() 
    Console.WriteLine("ITDepartment.txt has been created");
}
```